# Add space/new line between elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, appendchild

So I am attempting to display all the questions and responses from my Firebase database. It is showing up fine, but it looks ugly, because there is no space between the question and responses. I've tried using the `createElement` feature as well as `.innerHTML` to add a nonbreaking space. Nothing is working. Here is the code I have thus far: Thanks for your help!

```
<button id="all" onclick="button()"> View All </button>
<h4> All Users: </h4>

<script>
    function button(){
        var userRef = new Firebase("https://speedpoll-1fd08.firebaseio.com");
        userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                // key will be "fred" the first time and "barney" the second time
                var key = console.log(childSnapshot.key());
                // childData will be the actual contents of the child
                // var userInfo = console.log(childSnapshot.val());
                var element = document.getElementById("viewAll");
                var para = document.createElement("h5");

                var node = document.createTextNode("Question: " + childSnapshot.key());
                console.log(childSnapshot.child("Option1").child('Response1').val());
                var node1= document.createTextNode("Response 1: " + childSnapshot.child("Option1").child('Response1').val());
                //var space = document.createElement("&nbsp;");
                element.innerHTML += "&nbsp;";
                var node2= document.createTextNode("Response 2: " + childSnapshot.child('Option2').child('Response2').val());
                var node3= document.createTextNode("Response 3: " + childSnapshot.child('Option3').child('Response3').val());
                para.appendChild(node);
                //para.appendChild(space);
                para.appendChild(node1);
                para.appendChild(node2);
                para.appendChild(node3);
                element.appendChild(para);

            });
        });

    }
</script>
<div id="viewAll">
</div>
```

Comment: P.S. I have a button it's just not on the pasted code for some reason

Comment: Why don't you create a space using a simple <br> tag?

Comment: How do i implement that within javascript though?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line by adding an `<hr>` element, as explained here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479441

Like this one:

---

You can also add `<div>` sections for each element, and style the margins, paddings and borders with CSS. The same for `<p>` sections.

You can play around with this JSFiddle:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/jmgomez/n0e1ev8e/
```

Check this out also on how to style borders with CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: This doesn't really help. I appreciate the comment, but I do know how to use CSS. The problem is using javascript to create these elements. That's what I need to use.

Comment: So to be more elaborate, I'm creating a p element within the div with the id "viewAll", and putting the question and response pulled from the firebase database.

Comment: THE only problem is that it results in printing like this:

Comment: Question: How are you?Response 1: OkResponse 2: Good.

Comment: Hi Taras, normally it is better to decompose the question in atomic problems, as your question says "it looks ugly, because there is no space between the question and responses. " the solution to that problem is in the HTML/CSS domain. Once it looks good, the second leg is to make the DOM changes dynamically using javascript, by your code it seems you know how to do this as well. Sorry for my late reply, I have a job and this is on a "best effort" basis...